# JavaScript Collapse-All/Show-All Toggle Button for Collapsible Divs

Tags: javascript, css

I have some Collapsible divs on my website, here's one for example: http://dogs.bluskye.net/seeya/ (not me in the photo ;) ) using the following JavaScript/CSS & simplified html example below.

I have searched for a way to create a "collapse-all/show-all" button, but since I really don't know JavaScript, I'm having trouble using the examples I've seen with mine.

I've spent quite a bit of time modifying the current JavaScript/CSS I'm using, so I really don't want to scrap this for a different system - can someone help me create a button that when clicked can toggle between hide/show all based on the .inside div class I'm already using?

Thanks!!

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (!content.style.display || content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #007784;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 97%;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button.collapsible.active {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #007784;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.inside {
  padding: 0;
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

/*unrelated*/
.trials {width:100%;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Standard Novice</button>
<div class="inside">
  <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
      <td width="33%">BTCWWA</td>
      <td width="33%">PAC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button" class="collapsible">Jumpers Novice</button>
<div class="inside">
  <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">PNWSSC</td>
      <td width="33%">MHDPC</td>
      <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">March 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">March 2, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">March 3, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the question title to say "Collapse-All/Show-All Toggle" to be more accurate...  I'd like a button (that I can format with CSS) to "Collapse All", but make that button a toggle - so that after you 'Collpase All", the text on the button changes to "Show All" & it'll open them back up again when you click on the button again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using inline style:

```
.style.display = "none"
```

Use class:

```
.classList.toggle('hide');

.hide { display: none }
```

#### Demo

```js
const col = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");

for (let c of col) {
  c.addEventListener("click", collapse);
}

function collapse(e) {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  const content = this.nextElementSibling;
  content.classList.toggle('hide');
}

const all = document.querySelector(".all");

all.addEventListener('click', collapseAll);

function collapseAll(e) {
  const col = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
  const con = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  if (e.target.matches('.all')) {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    col.forEach((button, index) => {
      if (e.target.matches('.active')) {
        button.classList.add('active');
        con[index].classList.remove('hide');
      } else {
        button.classList.remove('active');
        con[index].classList.add('hide');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font: 900 18px/1.5 Verdana;
}

button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #007784;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 97%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  margin: 3px auto 0;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font: inherit;
}

.collapsible.active {
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.collapsible:hover,
.all:hover {
  background-color: #0066FF;
}

.content {
  padding: 0;
  width: 96.25%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: 500 16px/1.5 Arial;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.trials {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.all::before {
  content: 'Show ';
}

.all.active::before {
  content: 'Hide ';
}
```

```html
<button class="all active" type="button">All</button>
<button class="collapsible active" type="button">Novice</button>
<section class="content">
  <table class="trials">
    <tr>
      <td>GSDCO</td>
      <td>BTCWWA</td>
      <td>PAC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January 1, 2020</td>
      <td>January 1, 2020</td>
      <td>January 1, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>

<button class="collapsible active" type="button">Standard</button>
<section class="content">
  <table class="trials">
    <tr>
      <td>PNWSSC</td>
      <td>MHDPC</td>
      <td>GSDCO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March 1, 2020</td>
      <td>March 2, 2020</td>
      <td>March 3, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, I like the idea of fixing the JS I have to use the class instead of the style, but this way makes them all collapsed by default, when someone had helped me edit my JS the way it was to they were all expanded by default. So maybe that's what you're seeing & trying to fix? Not sure - but the toggle button you've created works like I want as far as hiding/showing all by clicking the button, but I'd like them all showing by default & I'd prefer the text on the button to start with "Hide All" & change to "Show All", are these things possible?

Comment: I will also style this toggle button differently than the other buttons with the collapsible divs, it'll be small so you don't have to worry about matching it. :) Thanks! (And you don't have to worry about making it prettier for this example by changing the font & fixing how things don't line up perfectly here, it's just because it's missing the rest of my CSS in this simplified example. You can see it in real action here: http://dogs.bluskye.net/seeya/ )

Comment: Hi @BluSkye218 , I had each `.content` start as `.content.hide` so now the `.hide` is removed from the HTML to start out open. Yeah, I have a habit of making CSS/HTML look as harmonious as possible and JavaScript to *"organically"* integrate (6+ years web developer).

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `.active` class is now initially in the HTML (if `.content` removes `.hide` all `buttons.active`). Also, the last two CSS rulesets added are what makes `"Show/Hide All"` text possible.

Comment: Thank you very much - I had to tweak some of the CSS to work with my website, but I love the way the JS logic works. Really appreciate it!! Check it out in action: http://dogs.bluskye.net/seeya/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, with Pure javascript now

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (!content.style.display || content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }

    function toggle(className, displayState) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.display = displayState;
        }
    }

    function addClass() {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"),
            len = buttons !== null ? buttons.length : 0,
            i = 0;
        for (i; i < len; i++) {
            buttons[i].className += " active";
        }
    }

    function removeClass() {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"),
            len = buttons !== null ? buttons.length : 0,
            i = 0;
        for (i; i < len; i++) {
            buttons[i].className -= " active";
        }
    }
    var colAll = document.getElementById("colapseAll");
    var insideDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("inside");
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible active');
    var flag = true;
    var showAllBtn = document.getElementById("showAll");
    var colAllBtn = document.getElementById("colAll");
    colAll.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
        if (flag) {
            addClass();
            toggle('inside', 'none');
            flag = !flag;
            colAllBtn.classList.remove('show');
            showAllBtn.classList.add('show');
        } else {
            toggle('inside', 'block');
            while(elements.length > 0){
       elements[0].classList.remove('active');
   }
   showAllBtn.classList.remove('show');
   colAllBtn.classList.add('show');
            flag = !flag;
        }
    });
```

```css
        .collapsible {
  background-color: #007784;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 97%;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button.collapsible.active {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #007784;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.inside {
  padding: 0;
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

/*unrelated*/
.trials {width:100%;}

#colapseAll span {display: none;}
#colapseAll span.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<button id="colapseAll"><span id="colAll" class="show">collapse all</span><span id="showAll">Show ALL</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Standard Novice</button>
    <div class="inside">
        <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr>
                <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
                <td width="33%">BTCWWA</td>
                <td width="33%">PAC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
                <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
                <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Jumpers Novice</button>
    <div class="inside">
        <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr>
                <td width="33%">PNWSSC</td>
                <td width="33%">MHDPC</td>
                <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="33%">March 1, 2020</td>
                <td width="33%">March 2, 2020</td>
                <td width="33%">March 3, 2020</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks!! Is it possible to make that button a toggle so you can collapse all & then it switched to "show all" & it'll open them back up again? And unfortunately I just don't know JavaScript or jQuery - it doesn't need to be solely JS - I don't care what it is, as long as it does what I need! :)

Comment: To follow up, the only things that worry me about linking to a jQuery like that is (1) what if that eventually stops working because its changed or removed from wherever it's hosted & (2) I will want to style it with CSS, which might be hard given that I don't see the whole code.

Comment: I have updated the code for you to pure javascript,

Comment: Changing the collapse button to toggle, just hang tight

Comment: Why are you querying all of the button objects if they're already defined with `coll`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution with pure Javascript.
You just have to wrap the script with

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   ...
});
```

to ensure the content has loaded before the script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (!content.style.display || content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
});
```

Replace that with your script and you're good to go

Comment: Adding that will allow me add a button to toggle hide/show all? How do I add the button to work with that?

Answer (score 0):

My logic: Since you've already created an array of objects, you can just use `Object.values` to iterate over it, and just check each if they're active or not.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (!content.style.display || content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function collapseAll() 
{
  Object.values(coll).forEach( (el) =>
  {
    if (!el.classList.contains("active"))
    {
      el.click();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #007784;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 97%;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button.collapsible.active {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #007784;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.inside {
  padding: 0;
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

/*unrelated*/
.trials {width:100%;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Standard Novice</button>
<div class="inside">
  <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
      <td width="33%">BTCWWA</td>
      <td width="33%">PAC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">January 1, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button" class="collapsible">Jumpers Novice</button>
<div class="inside">
  <table class="trials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2px">
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">PNWSSC</td>
      <td width="33%">MHDPC</td>
      <td width="33%">GSDCO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">March 1, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">March 2, 2020</td>
      <td width="33%">March 3, 2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button onClick="collapseAll()">Collapse All</button>
```

Comment: Hello, yes - having a button like that (but of course I'd format with CSS) to "Collapse All", but can you also make that button a toggle - so that after you 'Collpase All", the text on the button changes to "Show All" & it'll open them back up again when you click on it again? Thanks!!